# Defining a different XML layout depending on the device/screen size?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, screen-size, android-screen-support

I have read lots of post on this forum and others about using a different layout depending on the device being used.

Below is a screenshot of my layout folder at the moment:

[image: Layout folder]

Now, I have tried many different variations to try and get the XML layout to change. The project is designed using a phone and I'm now testing on a 10.1 inch Samsung Galaxy tablet.

Despite all those layouts my app still uses the default .xml file.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong or other variations to try?

I should say I lock the user into portrait mode hence a few layouts with -port.

Any help would be great

thanks

Comment: Am I right that the various layout folders are placed inside your default layout folder? They all should be on the same level, inside the res folder.

Comment: How have you tried to test them? Do you have all these different devices - in AVD ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have your layout-large, layout-sw400dp-port,... folders at the same level as your layout folder instead of having them inside the layout folder.
Your folder structure should look like -

> ```
> /res/layout/
> /res/layout-large/
> /res/layout-sw400dp-port/main.xml 
> ...
> ```